# How to fix "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to write request to stream" with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Env:

Python 3.9.7

selenium==3.141.0

Problem:

I'm trying to get an element on webSite with selenium.

```
button_LogIn = WebDriverWait(p_driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, ("//a[contains(@href,'https://www.reddit.com/login'"))))
```

But I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\Desktop\PhoneBot\PhoneBotV3\modules\robots\reddit\Reddit_Browser_Bot.py", line 510, in <module>
    RunRedditBrowser(p_browser, p_driver, p_function, p_taskuser_id,label_log,lock)
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\Desktop\PhoneBot\PhoneBotV3\modules\robots\reddit\Reddit_Browser_Bot.py", line 441, in RunRedditBrowser
    AreWeRedditLoggedIn(p_driver)
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\Desktop\PhoneBot\PhoneBotV3\modules\robots\reddit\Reddit_Browser_Bot.py", line 193, in AreWeRedditLoggedIn
    button_LogIn = WebDriverWait(p_driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 64, in __call__
    return _find_element(driver, self.locator)
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 415, in _find_element
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 411, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\mmetral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to write request to stream


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I search for this error message in google but I couldn't find anything.

Does anyone can help me please?

Comment: Could you give the website link or show the HTML code?

Comment: The webSite is Reddit homepage https://www.reddit.com/
I want to locate the login button

I had a misclick and the Xpath isn't good I give once again this line (I give up a part of Xpath )

    `code` button_LogIn = WebDriverWait(p_driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, ("//a[contains(@href,'https://www.reddit.com/login')]")))) `code`

Answer (score 0):

The `xpath` you were using was wrong. Try the following and the button will be clicked.

```
button_LogIn = WebDriverWait(p_driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, ("//*[@id='SHORTCUT_FOCUSABLE_DIV']/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a[1]"))))

# clicking the button
button_LogIn.click()
```

Comment: Same Problem with your Xpath :-S


raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to write request to stream